# i want to play .wav file at specific time in C# (window)

Tags: c#

i want to play .wav file at specify time like every hour 
how could to manage it in c# (window)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at using [SoundPlayer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) and [Timer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

For the timer, you would want to look at [Timer.OnTick Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.ontick%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)  and [Timer.Interval Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.interval%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)